# jpopupmenu where to add listener

Tags: swing, jpopupmenu

I have a jTextField with a button along side to call a popupmenu. The popupmenu contains a list of standard text for the jTextField.  This list is held in a list array of variable length, since it can be added too elsewhere in the program.

I'm using the following to generate the popupmenu.

```
    for(i=0;i<=menuArray1.size()-1;i++){
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem((String) menujlArray1.get(i));
        jPopupMenu1.add(item);
     }
```

My question is how do I include the listener that captures which item on the popup menu is selected so I can then put the value into the jTextField.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [ItemListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) interface. If your `JMenuItem` implements `ItemSelectable` interface. You can change your code to be like below:

```
ItemListener il =
  e -> {JMenuItem source = (JMenuItem)(e.getSource());
    String s = "Item event detected on '" + source.getText() +",New state: "
               + ((e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) ?
                 "selected":"unselected");
    jTextField.setText(s);
};

for(i=0;i<=menuArray1.size()-1;i++){
    JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem((String) menujlArray1.get(i));
    jPopupMenu1.add(item);
    item.addItemListener(il);   
}
```

More examples [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)

Comment: I understand the reply will place the string s into jTextField but it doesn't work.  Any suggestions?